# change node features in pytorch geometric

Tags: pytorch, feature-extraction, mnist, pytorch-geometric

I am trying to change node features of mnistsuperpixel of pytorch geometric dataset but features don't change. feature extraction part is done by a simple cnn which create a 10X1 feature. accuracy of extraction is not important, my goal is to just change the node feature.

this is the process :

```py
import torch
import torchvision

# Load the MNIST dataset
mnist_dataset = torchvision.datasets.MNIST(root='.', train=True, download=True, transform=torchvision.transforms.ToTensor())

# Define a model to extract features from the images
class FeatureExtractor(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(FeatureExtractor, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = torch.nn.Conv2d(1, 10, kernel_size=5)
        self.conv2 = torch.nn.Conv2d(10, 20, kernel_size=5)
        self.fc1 = torch.nn.Linear(320, 50)
        self.fc2 = torch.nn.Linear(50, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = torch.nn.functional.relu(torch.nn.functional.max_pool2d(self.conv1(x), 2))
        x = torch.nn.functional.relu(torch.nn.functional.max_pool2d(self.conv2(x), 2))
        x = x.view(-1, 320)
        x = torch.nn.functional.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = self.fc2(x)
        return x

model = FeatureExtractor()

# Extract features from the MNIST dataset
features = []
for i, (image, label) in enumerate(mnist_dataset):
    # Convert the image to a tensor and pass it through the model
    image = image.unsqueeze(0)
    feature = model(image).squeeze().tolist()

    # Save the feature and label to a list
    features.append((feature, label))

# Save the features to a file
with open('features.txt', 'w') as f:
    for feature, label in features:
        f.write(str(label) + ',' + ','.join([str(x) for x in feature]) + '\n')
```

now features are stored in features.txt

If I get value for features and dataset node features I'll get bellow :

`features[0]`

```py
([0.04065924137830734,
  -0.17148707807064056,
  -0.028605971485376358,
  -0.08014429360628128,
  0.049180179834365845,
  -0.02591242454946041,
  -0.08026853948831558,
  -0.13666193187236786,
  -0.07752594351768494,
  0.06033480912446976],
 5)
```

and

```py
dataset[0].x
```

```py
tensor([[0.6005],
        [0.7350],
        [0.5124],
        [0.7634],
        [0.5810],
        [0.7941],
        [0.7025],
        [0.6235],
        [0.7882],
        [0.5838],
        [0.5105],
        [0.2810],
        [0.5782],
        [0.7797],
        [0.4412],
        [0.6409],
        [0.2843],
        [0.7843],
        [0.6980],
        [0.5314],
        [0.8451],
        [0.7182],
        [0.2941],
        [0.6033],
        [0.8843],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000]])
```

```py
dataset[0].num_features # this will print 1
```

now change the node features :

```py
import torch
import torch_geometric.data
from torch_geometric.loader import DataLoader

# Load the MNIST superpixels dataset from PyG
dataset = torch_geometric.datasets.MNISTSuperpixels(root='.', train=True)

# Load the extracted features from the file
features = []
with open('features.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        label, feature_str = line.strip().split(',')[0], line.strip().split(',')[1:]
        feature = [float(x) for x in line.strip().split(',')[1:]]
        features.append((int(label), feature))

# Make sure the number of features matches the number of nodes in the dataset
assert len(features) == len(dataset)



# Create a list of Data objects with the label, edge index, pos, and features

for data, (label, feature) in zip(dataset, features):
    data.x = feature
```

So now after changing data.x value, node features are still same:

```py
dataset[0].x
```

```py
tensor([[0.6005],
        [0.7350],
        [0.5124],
        [0.7634],
        [0.5810],
        [0.7941],
        [0.7025],
        [0.6235],
        [0.7882],
        [0.5838],
        [0.5105],
        [0.2810],
        [0.5782],
        [0.7797],
        [0.4412],
        [0.6409],
        [0.2843],
        [0.7843],
        [0.6980],
        [0.5314],
        [0.8451],
        [0.7182],
        [0.2941],
        [0.6033],
        [0.8843],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000],
        [0.0000]])
```

```py
dataset[0].num_features # will print 1 again
```